# Is it possible to invoke external service APIs from an ADO extension?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-extensions

I want to send a message to a ServiceBus queue from ADO PR policy status menu extension.

I thought of below options:

- Get user token from ADO, then get user impersonation token for ServiceBus and send message. Is this possible?
- Create a service endpoint for ServiceBus connection string, but can't get connection string as this is a secret.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no default way to invoke external service APIs from an extension. As alternative, you can queue a build/release from the extension, and use [Publish To Azure Service Bus task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/publish-to-azure-service-bus?view=azure-devops) to send a message to an Azure Service Bus using a service connection.